# vscode - automatically convert tabs to spaces on save

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to configure vscode to make it automatically convert tabs to spaces on save, and I've found this under **File → Preferences → Settings → Text Editor**:

```json
Code Actions On Save
Code action kinds to be run on save.

Edit in settings.json
```

- When I click on `settings.json`, it opens:

  ```json
  {
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?",
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "explorer.autoReveal": false,
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {

    }
  }
  ```

  - I assume I need to add my action to the below, but what do I need to add here?

    ```json
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {

    }
    ```

How do I figure out all commands/actions I can use here, as Google was not helpful?